# Why isn't this 'if' statement working to call my function only if the condition is met?

Tags: javascript

I'm not the author of this code originally, so apologies for gaps in my knowledge.
I have this function, getRecommendations, which determines whether a user's current domain (parsed from url), matches any within an array called 'domains.'  If so, we want to call fetchRecommendations.  If no match, we should return without calling the function.  Right now, fetchRecommendations is being called regardless of the user's current domain.  I'm a bit stumped. Is it a misplaced return? Are we not calling fetchRecommendations correctly?  Grateful for any insight.

As a side note, it was suggested to me that the issue was the 'return.' But I tried different placements and it appeared to break the code.

```
export const getRecommendations = url =>

  browser.storage.local.get("domains").then(({ domains }) => {
    const domain = parseDomain(url);

    if (domains.includes(domain)) { 
      return fetchRecommendations(url);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  });

export const fetchRecommendations = url =>
  browser.storage.local.get("user").then(({ user }) =>
    fetch(trestle.api.recommendations, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ currentUrl: url, emailAddress: user.username }),
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(recommendation => recommendation)
    .catch(e => new Error("Unable to return recommendations for company"))
  );
```

I think this is where we set the domains to storage:

```
export const getAnalyzedDomains = () =>
  fetch(trestle.api.domains)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(domains =>
      browser.storage.local.set({ domains }).then(() => domains)
    );
```

Also, here is the parseDomain function, imported from a different file (This file imported parse from psl):

```
export const parseDomain = url => {
  if (url === undefined || url === null) {
    return "";
  }

  const protocol = url.indexOf("://");
  url = url.substr(protocol + 3, url.length);
  const pos = url.indexOf("/") === -1 ? url.length - 1 : url.indexOf("/");
  const domain = url.substr(0, pos);

  return parse(domain).domain || "";
};
```

Comment: Could you place this in a sandbox so that i can actually debug your code. Would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, @felix, Just looked up Sandbox, and am wondering whether you need the whole file in Sandbox or just the bit I've posted here?   I'm unsure if just this part would be out of context and whether that may interfere with the debugging, but let me know and I am happy to post it in sandbox.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you `console.log` `domain` & `domains` values?

Comment: John Deacon I would need the whole code. Otherwise the sandbox would not work. Only if it is possible for you to post the whole code.

Comment: Hi @karan, The odd thing is that when I console.log 'domain' and 'domains,' in my debug console, I get a 'badly placed ()s' error. In fact, I'm thinking maybe this is an issue I need to resolve first.  I do know domains is a giant array of .com's.

Comment: @felix, Oh I see. In that case, I may not be able to do it.  This is a browser extension with many interlinked files and dependencies.  I don't see it could work on Sandbox.  Thank you anyway, for the offer to look more into it!

Comment: I think I know what is wrong with your code. You need to plase a "{" after "url =>" in getRecommendations and close it afterwards. The same thing with fetchRecommendations.
I think that your syntax isn't quite correct

Comment: Are you sure that you need to destructure `{ domains }`? Try Just `domains` without `{}`. Also as felix said you're missing some opening and closing curly braces for your `getRecommendation` method. It would also be helpful to see how you set `domains` to the `storage` and see your `parseDomain` function.

Comment: Thank you, @felix and @Olivier@  I have now included the curly braces after url=> and closed it after fetchRecommendations.  I also tried just doing domains without {}, but even with both these changes I am getting the same result.  I will now edit this post to include setting domains to storage and parseDomain. Appreciate you all!